# Clipboard SetText fails whereas SetDataObject does not

Tags: c#

I was trying to copy a string to the clipboard via

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(someString);
```

and it was failing (`Clear`ing before setting before setting did not work because `Clear` also needs to open the clipboard). The call to `GetOpenClipboardWindow()` indicated that some window was keeping the clipboard open (in this case it was notepad++).

By changing the above line to:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(someString);
```

the call succeeds every time and the contents of the clipboard are what I expect.

Does anybody have an explanation for this behaviour?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597039(v=vs.110).aspx) does not state much about what it does differently (except for clearing the clipboard when the program exits).

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN

Clipboard.SetDataObject() :
This method attempts to set the data ten times in 100-millisecond intervals, and throws an ExternalException if all attempts are unsuccessful.

Clipboard.SetText(): Clears the Clipboard and then adds text data to it.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the code for the two methods, I see the following differences:

```
public static void SetText(string text, TextDataFormat format)
{
    if (text == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    }
    if (!DataFormats.IsValidTextDataFormat(format))
    {
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("format", (int)format, typeof(TextDataFormat));
    }
    Clipboard.SetDataInternal(DataFormats.ConvertToDataFormats(format), text);
}

[SecurityCritical]
public static void SetDataObject(object data, bool copy)
{
    SecurityHelper.DemandAllClipboardPermission();
    Clipboard.CriticalSetDataObject(data, copy);
}
```

The `SetDataObject` method is marked as security-critical, which might seem like the important difference. However, the `SetText` method eventually just calls `SetDataObject` internally. The difference being:

```
/* From SetText: */
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);

/* From SetDataObject: */
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, false);
```

`SetText(text)` never clears the Clipboard when the application exits, while `SetDataObject(object)` always does. That is the only real difference between calls. Try calling `SetDataObject(someString, false)` and `SetDataObject(SomeString, true)` to see any difference. If both behave the same, the difference must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think I'll need to read up on the Win32 API behind the calls to truly understand what is happening.